# having trouble with the responsiveness of the iframe in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, css-grid

I am trying to fit the Iframe in to the grid, but somehow it is floating around. Is there a way to fix the responsiveness?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="box3">
                <div class="wrapper_frame">
                    <iframe class="wrapper-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jmliox1trPQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="description"></iframe>
                </div>
                <h3>Box3</h3>

**CSS**
main{
    height: 200vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* displays the columns */
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
}
.box3{
    grid-column: 1/6;
    grid-row: 8/12;
}
/* the wrapper around the frame */
.wrapper_frame{
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper-iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The html is not complete but if the iframe wrapper is not fully responsive then you may use this

```css
.wrapper_frame {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper_frame::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  /* next line: iframe H:W, example 9:16 = 56,25% */
  padding-top: 56.25%; 
}
.wrapper_frame iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_frame">
  <iframe class="wrapper-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jmliox1trPQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="description"></iframe>
</div>
```